# Is one-sided standard normal a sub-gaussian?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

For example, does the positive part of the standard normal distribution satisfy sub-gaussian property?

Comment: $P(\vert X \vert >t)$ is the same for standard normal and one-sided standard normal.

Comment: I agree with you. One way of checking the sub-gaussianity by showing the moment generating function of that r.v. is upper bounded by exponential quantity. How do I establish the same for one-sided standard r.v. While doing that, I'm encountering an additional multiplier 2. I'm not sure how to get rid of it. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: This question is a simple special case of your subsequent question.

Comment: I don't think that the multiplier matters for sub-gaussianity. But anyway, the multiplier 2 happens in both cases. The normal distribution has two tails (negative - positive) the half normal distribution tail is twice as high, but there is only one tail.